# Bootstrap Container with full-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make a full-width container that haves the right margin at left?

[image: layout example]

At the left you can see the margin from .container and I dont want the margin at rigth and this content must have full width (with margin left)

Comment: instead of `.container` use `.container-fluid`

Comment: Go through this: [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

Comment: guys,  with container-fluid the margins are removed... I need the left one.

Answer (score 1):

This is solution for Bootstrap4, you can use .container-fluid-left for content expanded to left and .container-fluid-right for content expanded to right.

```
@mixin make-container-fluid-left-right($gutter: $grid-gutter-width) {
  padding-right: $gutter / 2;
  padding-left: $gutter / 2;
}
@mixin make-container-fluid-left($max-widths: $container-max-widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
      margin-right: calc((100% - #{$container-max-width}) / 2);
      width: calc(100% - ((100% - #{$container-max-width}) / 2));
    }
  }
}
@mixin make-container-fluid-right($max-widths: $container-max-widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
      margin-left: calc((100% - #{$container-max-width}) / 2);
      width: calc(100% - ((100% - #{$container-max-width}) / 2));
    }
  }
}
.container-fluid-left {
  @include make-container-fluid-left-right();
  @include make-container-fluid-left();
}
.container-fluid-right {
  @include make-container-fluid-left-right();
  @include make-container-fluid-right();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your problems, this is bootstrap `<div class="container"></div>` problem. Please get first a new section or div than you change the class 
`<div class="container-fluid"></div>`

Comment: with container-fluid the margins are removed... I need the left one

Comment: theres not in special with my html... Im using bootstrap: a container (or container fluid) with a row inside...

Comment: you didnt understand me... I need a div that starts (right) same as .container but ends at the end of the window (and not at the end of .container)